# How to find the 3rd largest population of a country by state

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table where there are three columns zipcode, state, total_population.

```
ZIPCODE STATE   POPULATION
11937   36  15511
11941   36  1822
11940   36  4933
12435   36  280
12063   36  441
64733   29  1251
64734   29  1952
64735   29  13653
```

I am looking for this

```
zipcode state third_highest_population
11941  36     1822
4733   29     1251
```

I cannot think of a way to find the third largest population each state..any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please, no screenshots. Use formatted text instead, and don't forget to specify the expected result as well. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Show your best not working attempt. And Links to pictures aren’t welcome on SO. All information should be shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to help rank zip code populations by state, then keep the third ranked for each state.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT zipcode, 
      state, 
      total_population, 
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY state ORDER BY total_population DESC) as ziprank
   FROM yourtable
) r
WHERE ziprank = 3
```

`RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` may all work here depending on your data. `DENSE_RANK()` insures you will get at least 1 (but maybe more) ranked at 3. The reason you may get more is if two zip codes share the same population in the state. That is highly unlikely though, so `DENSE_RANK()` is a good fit.

Comment: I was exactly looking for this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
select * from (
    select  your_table.*,  rank() over(partition by state order by totpop) rnk from your_table
) t
where 
rnk = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data

```
DECLARE @Data AS TABLE (zipcode INT, 
                        [state] VARCHAR(10), 
                        [total_population] INT
                        )
INSERT INTO @Data
SELECT 500010,'Ap',24524540 UNION ALL
SELECT 500020,'KA',47857441 UNION ALL
SELECT 500030,'TN',89456655 UNION ALL
SELECT 500040,'KL',45775475 UNION ALL
SELECT 500050,'UP',47411189 

DECLARE @N INT = 3 -- Specify highest total as you required
```

Using Co related sub query

```
SELECT * FROM @Data
Go
SELECT zipcode, 
       [state], 
       [total_population]
FROM @Data e1
WHERE @N-1 = ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [total_population]) 
              FROM @Data e2
              WHERE e2.[total_population] > e1.[total_population] )
```